# With 256 MB RAM, what is the maximum length of double array we can create?

Tags: java, memory

[Code Ranch](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/content/JavaRAQ.html) has this question:

> 28) If we have 256 MB RAM then what is the maximum length of double array we can create? (Ignore the jvm memory occupied and everything
>   else)
>
> Ans:
>    Integer.MAX_VALUE  as the length() method must return correct 'int' length.

I'm not sure if I understand the answer which they had provided. From what I know, most implementations uses 64-bit for a double which means we can fit roughly 4 194 304 doubles (minus overhead) in 256 MB RAM.

So how could the maximum length of a double array be 2147483647 in a 256 MB RAM environment ?

Surely the test code below would give us OOM right?:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] d = new double[java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8];
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you arrive at `4 194 304`? I get 32 MB for that number times 64 bit.

Comment: arrays don't have a `length()` method. I can only assume the questioner hasn't been careful with his choice of words.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDIT: The answer below assumes that the question is asking about the size of array which can be allocated *within the 256MB specified in the question*. If that *isn't* the point of the question, then there is **no** definitive answer - because the maximum length will entirely depend on how much memory has been allocated to the JVM, how the JVM is able to use the memory etc. We may have 256MB of memory, but run a Sun JVM with -Xmx64M, so have even less than 256MB available.

So either the question is bad, or the answer is wrong - or quite possibly both.

---

The Code Ranch answer is definitely incorrect: 256MB is 2<sup>8</sup> * 2<sup>20</sup> bytes - i.e. 2<sup>28</sup> bytes. Each `double` value takes 8 bytes, so even leaving aside any overhead for the object and the length, the maximum number of `double` values you can store in 256MB is 2<sup>23</sup>. `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is 2<sup>31</sup> - 1, which is clearly much bigger.

(It's not a matter of "most implementations" using 64 bits for `double`, by the way - it's required by the spec.)

So yes, your test code would indeed give an OOM if you only had 256MB of memory available.

Given that some of the questions on that page don't even *have* answers, this answer is definitely incorrect, and others are badly written, I would just ignore the page completely.

Comment: @artbristol: From the question: "Ignore the jvm memory occupied and everything else" - I took that to include other virtual memory.

Comment: Swap space is seldomly located in the RAM.

Comment: @LinusKleen: I'm not sure what point you're trying to make, but the way I read the question, it's asking about the maximum size of array you can allocate if all the memory available to the array is 256MB. It's definitely a poorly worded question - which is in line with the rest of the page, unfortunately.

Comment: *"If we have 256 MB **RAM** then what is..."* I was referring to artbristol's question about swap space.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what swap space you have, amount of memory that the OS requires, Amount of memory for the VM+program ....

So there is no definitive answer.

Comment: It's explicitly stated that these should be ignored.

Comment: WHat does swap space have to do with this? You assign a certain amount of memory to the JVM. In the context of the question it is clear that 256MB _is_ available.

Comment: Actually this answer is right or at least more accurate than Jon Skeet's. The question does not state what JVM is used and a JVM might be able use as much memory as it can allocate from the OS (i.e. the old Microsoft VM did this). So a JVM could successfully allocate a array that is far too big to fit in physical RAM.

Comment: The thing is that some processes (e.g OS) requires stuff to be always in phywsical memory. The question is spurious to ignore other things running on that computer.

Comment: The OS has to juggle. Perhaps the JWM gets a little more or a little less

Answer (score 0):

You can theoretically allocate everything that you address space allows to -- it is when you try to actually *use* that address space that you can have problems.

So, the answer is partially correct: if you have a 64bit OS (*and* JVM), you address space is large enough for the whole world, however array indices are integers, a0nd the maximum value of an integer in Java is indeed `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (2^31 - 1). This is not so with a 32bit OS, though, because the available address space isn't enough that large in bytes.

But what you can actually write to is limited by the amount of RAM, so 2^(28-3) == 2^25 is the amount of doubles you can fit in memory, ignoring everything else.